# how to add text on an image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I loaded an image to my html page. I set its opacity to 0.5 using jquery css property. Now 
I want to write a text based sentence on the top of this image. I mean to say that the image I loaded I want it to be in background and the text to appear on top.

It is just like quoted image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            div{
              position:absolute;
              top:40px;
              left:40px;
              width:500px;
              height:500px;
            }
            #imgDiv{
              width:500px;
              height:500px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("img").css("opacity", 0.5);                
            });            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <img src="936371_607068789305456_425546376_n.jpg" id="imgDiv"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the css of the image by to set the image below all other DOM elements :

```
       #imgDiv{
          position: absolute;
          width:500px;
          height:500px;
          z-index: -1;
       }
```

Comment: how should i add it with php @prabhat jain

Comment: This is css. You have to add this with HTMl. Doesn't matter if it is java,php,.net.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to imgDiv CSS code:

```
position:relative;
z-index:0;
```

This makes the image act like a layer so we can put text on top of it the same way.
Now for the text make a new `<div>` or `<p>`, give it an ID, and write this CSS code to it:

```
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```

This will make the text on top of the photo. Now use `top:` `bottom:` `left:` `right:` in the same CSS if you needed to move the text around.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img class="transparency" src="img.jpg" />
    <div class="img-text">
        Image is loaded.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.transparency {
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}

.img-text {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This should be sufficient. It tells the img-text class to be on top of the transparency class.

Answer (score -2):

Just put you image as a div background in CSS.

```
background-image: url(images/yourimage.jpg);
```

Comment: Doesn't help with the opacity.

Comment: Add this to your div.     -khtml-opacity:.50; 
     -moz-opacity:.50; 
     -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=50)";
     filter:alpha(opacity=50);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
     opacity:.50;